# Difference between individual and standalone

Tags: meaning, differences

I am wondering what is difference between these two words. My dictionary says that they both stands for the same thing. Is that true? I do not think so. Please can you explain me usage of both of these words? Thank you a lot.

Comment: There are lots of differences according to context. In computing, for example, a *standalone process* probably means one which has its own execution thread running directly under the operating system rather than being a "slave" process within some other app (and you probably wouldn't call that an "individual process"). Or consider *the individual responsible for the Nice massacre*, where we'd never call him *the standalone*. In short, this question is unclear. What's the context? What do you already know from dictionaries?

Comment: Welcome to ELU. What does your research show? Can you list dictionary definitions and a few example sentences and explain to us what confuses you most?

Comment: Which dictionary did you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Standalone* (more often *stand-alone*) means, according to the OED

> **stand-alone**, *adj*, *computing*: designating a part of a computer system that can be used independently.

This is the only listed definition, which is strange. I have heard it use outside of the context of computing.

Wiktionary gives

> **stand-alone**, *adj*, operating, functioning, or existing without additions or assistance; independent; able to be separate or separated.

*Individual* on the other hand means something else. Common usages include, per the OED,

> **individual**, *adj*
>
> 3.a of, relating to, or characteristic of a single person, organism, or thing.
>
> 4.a existing as a separate indivisible entity; numerically one; single.
>
> 5 distinguished in nature or attributes from others; having a striking or unusual character; distinctive.

It is concerning that your dictionary gave them as synonyms. These definitions make the difference between the words fairly explicit. I cannot imagine a case in which they could be used interchangeably.

Comment: "individual" can also be a noun, which "standalone" cannot.